# How to count and group by range using Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an amount column in a table and i want to get different value by every 1000 range and count it

I have tried query below it gets only a count of amount where status is 1.

but my table already have "id" column as a unique value.
so i don't know how to make amount as "count" and amount name as "id".

```
x.find({
                where: { status: 1},
        attributes: [
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 100 AND amount <= 1000 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 100~1000'],
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 1001 AND amount <= 2000 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 1001~2000'],
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 2001 AND amount <= 3000 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 2001~3000'],
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 3001 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 3001~4000'],
        ],

    });
```

current output:

```
{
        "amount 100~1000": 3,
        "amount 1001~2000": 3,
        "amount 2001~3000": 1,
        "amount 3001~4000": 0,
}
```

what i want is

```
{
    "id":1, // amount 100~1000
    "count": 3,
},
{
    "id":2, // amount 1001~2000
    "count": 3,
},
{
    "id":3, // amount 2001~3000
    "count": 1,
},
```

Comment: any reason why you aren't executing a raw query for this?

Comment: im trying to practice sequelize @Rinkesh P

Comment: add id attribute in array of attributes: ['id', [],[],[]]

Comment: im sorry i didn't mentioned that my table already have id column @MuhammadFazeel Fazeel

Comment: replace attributes with this...

 attributes: ['id',
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 100 AND amount <= 1000 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 100~1000'],
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 1001 AND amount <= 2000 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 1001~2000'],
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 2001 AND amount <= 3000 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 2001~3000'],
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 3001 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 3001~4000'],
        ]

Answer (score 0):

Use `findAndCountAll` instead of just `find`. then use `group` attribute with it

```js
x.findAndCountAll({
                where: { status: 1},
        attributes: [
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 100 AND amount <= 1000 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 100~1000'],
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 1001 AND amount <= 2000 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 1001~2000'],
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 2001 AND amount <= 3000 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 2001~3000'],
            [literal('COUNT (CASE WHEN amount >= 3001 THEN amount END)'), 'amount 3001~4000'],
        ],
        group: ["amount", "id"] //<= I assumed that you have a table called amount because you did not provide a full information
    });
```

Also I noticed that you treat the ORMs like plain SQL using `literal` which is unnecessary in your case, you can use operators instead e.g `[Op.between]`, please refer to the [docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators) for more info on how to use operators.